# Why does talk in chat still require 20 reputation on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat, meta, privileges

**Alert! low rep user here!** I'm trying to work on my rep by participating more around the StackExchange. It can be a little daunting though, writing a question and wondering if it will be well received... I was thinking if I could run an occasional idea by someone in chat, it might save me from writing a bad/duplicate/one-word-answer question, and I think would probably save everybody some time.

The problem is that at my current meta reputation level of 7, how am I supposed to achieve this? Do I post a comment somewhere? Do I post a whole new question?

So basically my question is, **why is the required reputation for `talk in chat` privilege still at 20 here in meta?** `Comment everywhere` has been lowered to 5, whereas it's usually at 50. Why is `talk in chat` still 20?

Related:

- [meta.se-2018 Why do this site's privileges' costs differ from all the other SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307044/why-do-this-sites-privileges-costs-differ-from-all-the-other-se-sites)
- [meta.se-2011 Do the reputation limits make as much sense on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/do-the-reputation-limits-make-as-much-sense-on-meta)
- [meta.se-2010 Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared/160292#160292)

#### Edit

Oops found it! [meta.se-2010 Why do you need 25 reputation on Meta to use chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59728/why-do-you-need-25-reputation-on-meta-to-use-chat)
 although 8+ years old. is it still relevant? I swear i searched before posting...

Comment: Because no one bothered to touch it. FYI: Your reputation for Stack Exchange general chat (not Meta Stack Exchange chat) considers your overall earned rep (not including the default 1 for signing up), not your rep on a specific site.

Comment: Also, moderators have the ability to allow specific users to talk in specific rooms even if they have less than 20 rep. The ability for room owners and/or high-rep users to do this [has been requested and rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat).

Comment: i tried to enter a room on meta, but it said: You must have 20 reputation on Meta Stack Exchange to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange have their own separate chat servers, and only check reputation on those specific sites.

Comment: Perhaps there could be a special room for low rep user?

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/282094

Comment: right I can chat on superuser and a few others...

Comment: Are you aware of the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)? Once you get 200 rep on one site you'll be able to talk in chat on *any* site you join.

Comment: That would be extremely difficult, since a mod has to individually allow each user access. That said, there is also a room for general meta issues on the general Stack Exchange chat server, [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly).

Comment: The reason why MSE has its own chat server is historical, because in a past life each site would get its own chat server; during this time, several staff-internal chat rooms were set up on the one for MSE, which is what is currently blocking it from being merged with the general server like all the other sites were.